# Package titleps: redefined plain page style footer being used by redefined empty page style

Tags: header-footer, titlesec, titleps

I'm using `titlesec` package with `pagestyles` option to redefine both `plain` and `empty` page styles. But when compile the code below, the `empty` page uses `plain` footer.

Code:

```
% Início do preâmbulo
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}

%% \usepackages diversos
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[top=30mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[clearempty,pagestyles]{titlesec}

%% Definições de fonte
\setmainfont{LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf,ItalicFont=LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf]
\setsansfont{LiberationSans-Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=LiberationSans-Bold.ttf,ItalicFont=LiberationSans-Italic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf]
\setmonofont{LiberationMono-Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=LiberationMono-Bold.ttf,ItalicFont=LiberationMono-Italic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf]
\setstretch{1.15}

%% \setlenghts diversos
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}

%% \setcounters diversos
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%% Definições para o pacote hyperref
\hypersetup{linktoc=all,colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}

%% \renewcommands diversos
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\arabic{enumiv}}
\addto\captionsbrazilian{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}}

%% Definições de novos estilos de página
\renewpagestyle{empty}{%
    \setheadrule{0pt}%
    \setfootrule{0pt}%
    \sethead[][][]{}{}{}%
    \setfoot[][][]{}{}{}%
}%
\renewpagestyle{plain}[\scriptsize]{%
    \setheadrule{0pt}%
    \setfootrule{1pt}%
    \footrule{}%
    \setfoot[][ - \thepage{} - ][]{}{ - \thepage{} - }{}%
}%
\newpagestyle{agradecimento}[\scriptsize]{%
    \setheadrule{0pt}%
    \setfootrule{1pt}%
    \footrule{}%
    \setfoot[][ - \thepage - ][]{}{ - \thepage - }{}%
}%

% Fim do preâmbulo

% Início do documento
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter[Capa]{}
\begin{center}
    \vfill
    {\bfseries\Huge Thalassia\par}
    \vspace{1em}
    {\Large Um mundo de exploração e aventuras para \emph{Dungeon World}\par}
    \vspace{1em}
    por Lu Cavalheiro\par
    \vfill
    {\small Licença: Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0\par}
    {\small 2020\par}
    \vfill
    \hspace{0pt}
\end{center}
\clearpage
\pagestyle{agradecimento}
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\chapter{Agradecimentos}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

As seen on image, page 1 (used as title page) has same footer page 2 has, but page 1 is set to `empty` page style and page 2, `plain`. How to prevent page 1 from using page 2 footer?

Answer (score 1):

Don't redefine the `empty` page style – just use `\thispagestyle{empty}` right after the first  `\chapter`. Also, you don't have to use `\setheadrule{0pt}` if you want no head rule: contrary to `fancyhdr`, you just have not to use `\headrule`.

Also, always load `hyperref`  last (very few exceptions – most notably `cleveref`) and it is recommended to load the language option with \documentclass, so that all language dependent packages be informed.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside, brazilian]{book}

%% \usepackages diversos
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[top=30mm,left=20mm,right=20mm,bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[clearempty ,pagestyles]{titlesec}%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Definições de fonte
\setmainfont{LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf,ItalicFont=LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf]
\setsansfont{LiberationSans-Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=LiberationSans-Bold.ttf,ItalicFont=LiberationSans-Italic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf]
\setmonofont{LiberationMono-Regular.ttf}[BoldFont=LiberationMono-Bold.ttf,ItalicFont=LiberationMono-Italic.ttf,BoldItalicFont=LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf]
\setstretch{1.15}

%% \setlenghts diversos
\setlength{\parindent}{1.25cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\columnsep}{5mm}

%% \setcounters diversos
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%% Definições para o pacote hyperref
\hypersetup{linktoc=all,colorlinks=true,allcolors=black}

%% \renewcommands diversos
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\arabic{enumi}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiii}{\arabic{enumiii}}
\renewcommand{\labelenumiv}{\arabic{enumiv}}
\addto\captionsbrazilian{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Índice}}

%% Definições de novos estilos de página
\renewpagestyle{plain}[\scriptsize]{%
    \setfootrule{1pt}%
    \footrule{}%
    \setfoot[][ - \thepage{} - ][]{}{ - \thepage{} - }{}%
}%
\newpagestyle{agradecimento}[\scriptsize]{%
    \setfootrule{1pt}%
    \footrule{}%
    \setfoot[][ - \thepage - ][]{}{ - \thepage - }{}%
}%

% Fim do preâmbulo
\usepackage{lipsum}
% Início do documento
\begin{document}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter[Capa]{}\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \vfill
    {\bfseries\Huge Thalassia\par}
    \vspace{1em}
    {\Large Um mundo de exploração e aventuras para \emph{Dungeon World}\par}
    \vspace{1em}
    por Lu Cavalheiro\par
    \vfill
    {\small Licença: Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0\par}
    {\small 2020\par}
    \vfill
    \hspace{0pt}
\end{center}

\chapter{Agradecimentos}
\pagestyle{agradecimento}
\pagenumbering{Alph}

\end{document}
```